# Create SubscriptionCloudCredentials for WebSiteManagementClient without Azure AD Application

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sdk-.net, azure-management-api

I'm looking for a simple solution to Authenticate and use the `WebSiteManagementClient`. The [examples](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/b2a3d67a90b7b2d673d68dab553f82e015333d10/ManagementLibrarySample/Program.cs#L114) I've seen utilize an Azure AD Application to create the `SubscriptionCloudCredentials` required. I would prefer to create the `SubscriptionCloudCredentials` without the use of an AD Application.

If at all possible, I would prefer to just use the Web Deploy un/pw credentials found in the Publish Profile Settings XML (as I already have code that uses these to interact with the kudu api with basic auth)

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691148/simplest-way-to-access-azure-programmatically/37698682#37698682) potential solution that instead uses a [management certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-certs-create) ([more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-api-management-certs)). But again, if at all possible, I would prefer to just use the Web Deploy un/pw.

(I understand the management cert is at a subscription level, and the Web Deploy un/pw are at a App Service/WebSite instance level. I'm just stating what my desired solution would look like.)

Answer (score 1):

Management certificates allow you to authenticate only with the classic deployment **(Azure Service Management)** model and not the Azure Resource Management deployment model.

If your web app is not created using the classic deployment model, you'll need a `TokenCloudCredential` instead of the `CertificateCloudCredential`.

Technically, you can still create `Certificate-based SubscriptionCloudCredentials` but it will only work with Azure web app created with the classic deployment model.

Answer (score 0):

> I would prefer to just use the Web Deploy un/pw.

If you want to upload certificate to Azure WebApp during Web Deploy then we can use ARM template , more details please refer to the [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-web-arm-with-msdeploy-provision.md).

```
{
    "name": "[parameters('certificateName')]",
    "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
        "pfxBlob": "pfx base64 blob",
        "password": "some pass"
    }
}
```

About how to create subscriptionCloudCredentials with certificate and how to create customized cert, I did a demo for it. More details please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231598/azure-website-scaling).

> If we try to run the project on the Azure. Please refer to document [Using Certificates in Azure Websites Applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/). Adding an app setting named WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES with its value set to the thumbprint of the certificate will make it accessible to your web application

So we also need to add the AppSetting in the ARM template, more detail info please refer to the [document](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/03/azure-arm-template-define-web-app-application-settings/).

```
{
   "name": "appsettings",
    "type": "config",
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]"
    ],
    "tags": {
        "displayName": "WebAppSettings"
    },
    "properties": {
        " WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES ": "thumbprint "
    }
```